# python import dictionary outside function in another file as variable

Tags: python, dictionary, aws-lambda

Can you please suggest how to send dictionary from one function to another?

Below is my code and i want to import finallist dictionary outside this function and inside another separate python file as variable.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
        val = ec2list()
        global k
        global v
        global keyvalue
        #print(val)
        print(type(val))
        for k,v in val.items():
            ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
            parameter = ssm.get_parameter(Name=v,  WithDecryption=True)
            keyvalue = parameter['Parameter']['Value']
            finallist[k]=keyvalue
            print(finallist)
```

Comment: introduce all files with which you working

Comment: why you can't return finallist dictionary from this function?

Comment: I want to execute fabric file and below is its detail  . I want to use some variable from above code such as k & keyvalue 

host=k

print(k)
#print(keyvalue)

env.hosts=host
env.user="ubuntu"
env.key_filename=keyvalue
#env.key_filename=keyvalue
env.keepalive=10


def remote_uname():
    put('/root/d.sh', '/tmp/alert.sh')
    try:
        run('ls -lh /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/aws/bin/aws')
    except:
        print "File not found so Now Copying"
        run('sudo apt-get install unzip -y')
    run('chmod +x /tmp/disk-alert.sh')
    run('/tmp/disk-alert.sh')